# Android studio emulator can't connect to camera

Tags: android, camera, android-emulator

I'm connecting a webcam to my emulator by camera to "webcam0" in the AVD Manager. When I launch the webcam from emulator, I get the following window:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwJoP.png)

I unistalled Android Studio too, but i didn't solved it. Please give me some solution.